# fetching last inserted id while inserting values concurrently by multiple users at the same instance

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using `mysql_insert_id()` to fetch the last inserted `id`. I have a confusion about which `id` it gives when inserting values concurrently by multiple users at the same instance. Does it gives the one that I have inserted or does it compare the last query within same instance?

Comment: if gives the last id inserted in that _session_, which is effectively per connection

Comment: Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query

Comment: You should NOT use mysql_* functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: the last one you inserted.

Here's why.

The php functions that retrieve the last inserted ids are wrappers around the mysql library function `mysql_insert_id()`.  The server tracks the most recently generated `AUTO_INCREMENT` value on a per connection basis, and is not affected by another connection generating an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value.

[20.6.14.3 How to Get the Unique ID for the Last Inserted Row](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

> For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in
>   the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another
>   client. It is not even changed if you update another AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column with a nonmagic value (that is, a value that is not NULL and
>   not 0). Using LAST_INSERT_ID() and AUTO_INCREMENT columns
>   simultaneously from multiple clients is perfectly valid. Each client
>   will receive the last inserted ID for the last statement that client
>   executed.